# Python: can't convert "None" or empty string values in a list

Tags: python, list

I have this list called query1:

```
[['PD', '', '', '', None, None, None, Decimal('43194'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('1000'), Decimal('500'), Decimal('67300'), Decimal('500'), Decimal('24426'), Decimal('2400'), Decimal('109700'), Decimal('1895'), Decimal('34000'), Decimal('100000'), None, None, Decimal('7900'), Decimal('1594'), None, None, Decimal('45900'), Decimal('12500'), None, Decimal('430'), Decimal('4550'), None, Decimal('11000'), Decimal('33700'), None, Decimal('10100'), Decimal('13500'), None, None, None, Decimal('96282'), Decimal('1000'), Decimal('2450'), Decimal('3700'), Decimal('19657'), Decimal('190700'), Decimal('7200'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('34650'), None, None, Decimal('1070'), None, Decimal('23200'), Decimal('200'), None, None, Decimal('42200'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('2000'), Decimal('7058'), None, Decimal('0'), None, None, None, Decimal('39900'), None, Decimal('21250'), Decimal('500'), Decimal('2000'), None, Decimal('4000'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('21900'), Decimal('349950'), Decimal('1200'), None], ['VE', '', '', '', None, None, None, Decimal('20700'), Decimal('0'), None, None, Decimal('65000'), Decimal('9300'), Decimal('8920'), Decimal('200'), Decimal('26500'), Decimal('2000'), Decimal('10850'), Decimal('73000'), None, None, Decimal('3000'), None, None, None, Decimal('11700'), Decimal('6000'), None, None, None, None, Decimal('500'), Decimal('300'), None, Decimal('1000'), Decimal('20000'), None, None, None, Decimal('7000'), None, Decimal('0'), Decimal('26500'), Decimal('5300'), Decimal('7000'), Decimal('3500'), None, Decimal('15000'), None, None, None, None, Decimal('13000'), Decimal('1000'), None, None, Decimal('19400'), Decimal('0'), None, Decimal('9900'), None, None, None, None, None, Decimal('32000'), None, Decimal('3000'), None, None, None, Decimal('3000'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('2000'), Decimal('18300'), None, None]]
```

And I want to change all the None and '' values to zeroes, but when I try this code:

```
    for i in range(len(query1)):
        for j in range(1, len(query1)):
            try:
                int(query1[i][j]) > 0
            except ValueError:
                query1[i][j] = 0

    print(query1)
```

this is the result I get:

```
[['PD', 0, '', '', None, None, None, Decimal('43194'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('1000'), Decimal('500'), Decimal('67300'), Decimal('500'), Decimal('24426'), Decimal('2400'), Decimal('109700'), Decimal('1895'), Decimal('34000'), Decimal('100000'), None, None, Decimal('7900'), Decimal('1594'), None, None, Decimal('45900'), Decimal('12500'), None, Decimal('430'), Decimal('4550'), None, Decimal('11000'), Decimal('33700'), None, Decimal('10100'), Decimal('13500'), None, None, None, Decimal('96282'), Decimal('1000'), Decimal('2450'), Decimal('3700'), Decimal('19657'), Decimal('190700'), Decimal('7200'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('34650'), None, None, Decimal('1070'), None, Decimal('23200'), Decimal('200'), None, None, Decimal('42200'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('2000'), Decimal('7058'), None, Decimal('0'), None, None, None, Decimal('39900'), None, Decimal('21250'), Decimal('500'), Decimal('2000'), None, Decimal('4000'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('21900'), Decimal('349950'), Decimal('1200'), None], ['VE', 0, '', '', None, None, None, Decimal('20700'), Decimal('0'), None, None, Decimal('65000'), Decimal('9300'), Decimal('8920'), Decimal('200'), Decimal('26500'), Decimal('2000'), Decimal('10850'), Decimal('73000'), None, None, Decimal('3000'), None, None, None, Decimal('11700'), Decimal('6000'), None, None, None, None, Decimal('500'), Decimal('300'), None, Decimal('1000'), Decimal('20000'), None, None, None, Decimal('7000'), None, Decimal('0'), Decimal('26500'), Decimal('5300'), Decimal('7000'), Decimal('3500'), None, Decimal('15000'), None, None, None, None, Decimal('13000'), Decimal('1000'), None, None, Decimal('19400'), Decimal('0'), None, Decimal('9900'), None, None, None, None, None, Decimal('32000'), None, Decimal('3000'), None, None, None, Decimal('3000'), Decimal('0'), Decimal('2000'), Decimal('18300'), None, None]]
```

I have also tried:

```
    for i in range(len(query1)):
        for j in range(1, len(query1)):
            if query1[i][j] is None or query[i][j] == 'None' or type(query[i][j]) is None or query1[i][j] == '':
                query[i][j] = 0
            else:
                query[i][j] = int(str(query[i][j]))
```

And the result is exactly the same. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: too much data. reduce it to the smallest subset that shows the issue

Comment: Looks like you got caught up in making your code unnecessarily complex. Also, as a general rule, if you find yourself using `for i in range(len(x)):`, your code would probably be cleaner if you replace it with `for i, elem in enumerate(x):`

Answer (score 2):

You may use nested *List Comprehension* here. Let's say your list is stored in variable as `my_list`, do

```
my_list = [[0 if item in [None, ''] else item for item in sub_list] for sub_list in my_list]
```

If it is ok to have `Decimal('0')`, instead of `0`. You may do:

```
my_list = [[item or Decimal('0') for item in sub_list] for sub_list in my_list]
```

Comment: `if item else` can be simply `or`. And you've got a typo with your variable names.

Comment: Also note that this changes `Decimal('0')` to `0`.

Comment: And it is not exactly correct as Decimal('0') evaluates to False. Just do if item is None or item is ''

Comment: Thank you everyone for the comments. Updated the answer

Comment: I'm guessing `or Decimal('0')` would make more sense anyway.

Comment: @wim: Agree with you

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is in the second line. You are looping over length of main list.

Change it to:

```
for j in range(1, len(query1[i])):
```

and it should work. Also it's better to check the value with simple if statement:

```
if query[i][j] in (None, ''):
    query[i][j] = 0
```

You can also use list comprehension, but it's more advanced and it will take you some time to get used to it.

Comment: Oh my, how could I not notice that? Thank you so much

Comment: You beat me to it :) Why not just `range(len(query1[i])` though?

Comment: @JulienMarrec I thought it was done on purpose as the first element was some 'PD'  country code tag. Of course you can loop from start if you want.

Comment: Exactly, the first element is not relevant

Comment: Good point! Too much data, I couldn't see that it was the case on both sublists!

Answer (score 2):

You have a list in a list, so you have to iterate over this two lists:

```
new_list = [] 
for outer_list_item in query1:
    temp_list = [] 
    for inner_list_item in outer_list_item:
        if inner_list_item in (None, ''):
            temp_list.append(0)
        else:
            temp_list.append(inner_list_item) 
    new_list.append(temp_list)
```

Comment: This will because work as you are just setting the item without changing the list.

Answer (score 1):

So, the most Pythonic way to remove empty values(None, '', etc.) from list is filtering it:

```
test_list = ['something', None, '', False, 25, [1,2,3,4], (2,3)]
filtered_list = filter(None, test_list)
print filtered_list

['something', 25, [1, 2, 3, 4], (2, 3)]
```

If you have a list of lists, you may use filter in a single for loop(or to use a comprehension list)